# can't get data from Django to html

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST['data']
        context = {'mydata': data}
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
    else:
        html_template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
        HttpResponse(html_template.render(request))
```

index.html:

```html
<form method = 'POST' id = 'post-form'>
      <select name = 'data' id = 'data'> 
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" name = 'post-form'> submit </button>
</form>

<h2> {{ mydata}} </h2> // this line print nothing.
```

When I click the submit button, I can access data from html submit in views.py.

However, I can't access `mydata` from Django in html.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your data handling is probably invalid, I would print data before assigning context and see what is done here (just using standard debugging way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are minor mistakes in the code:

1. You need to return HttpResponse so `return HttpResponse(html_template.render(request))`, but I'd recommend you to directly use `return render(request, 'home/index.html')`.
2. Also need to place `{% csrf_token %}` while dealing with POST data inside form, unless you have mentioned `@csrf_exempt` decorator on view.

So, try this code:

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        context = {'mydata': data}
        return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/index.html')
                    # OR  #
        # html_template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
        # return HttpResponse(html_template.render({}, request))
```

index.html:

```html
<form method='POST' id='post-form'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name='data' id='data'> 
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name='post-form'> submit </button>
</form>
    
<h2> {{mydata}} </h2>
```